# C - Freshly allocated char* contains existing data

Tags: c, pointers, char, malloc

C programming newbie here...

I have a function which does some maths and stores the result in an output variable:

```
void myFunction(char* output) {
   unsigned char myData[64]={0};

   // Call to another function which fills the 'myData' array
   compute(myData);

   // Now let's format the result in our output variable
   for (int n=0; n<64; n++) {
      sprintf(output, "%s%02x", myData[n]);
   }
}
```

The output char array is allocated by the caller in a variable called `result`:

```
void main(void) {
   char* result = NULL;
   result = malloc(129 * sizeof(unsigned char)); // twice the size of myData + 1 ending byte
   myFunction(result);
   // process result here
   // (...)

   free(result);
}
```

Problem is I *always* get some garbage stuff at the beginning of `result`, for instance:

> ���˶ang/String;8fb5ab60ed2b2c06fa43d[...]

Here the expected data starts at `8fb5ab60ed2b2c06fa43d`. After doing some logs, I know that `result` already contains `���˶ang/String;` *before* the sprintf() loop.

I don't understand how this can occur: isn't the malloc() function supposed to reserve memory for my variable? I guess this garbage comes from another memory area, which will eventually lead to some funky behavior...

That said, I've found a workaround just by adding a null ending byte at the 1st position of `result`, before calling the function:

```
    result[0]='\0'; // initialisation
    myFunction(result);
```

Now it works perfectly but I highly doubt that's good practice... Any advice?

Comment: `malloc` doesn't initialize the memory. You're getting ... what was there before. Always initialize your strings like you did.

Comment: [different context, same principle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/2371524) ;)

Comment: The problem isn't reading uninitialized bytes, it's appending to `output` incorrectly with invalid format specifiers to `printf`.  Reopening.

Comment: Save time: enable all compiler warnings - A good compiler will  warned about `sprintf(output, "%s%02x", myData[n]);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
for (int n=0; n<64; n++) {
   sprintf(output, "%s%02x", myData[n]);
}
```

Your format specifier to `sprintf` expects a `char *` followed by an `unsigned int`.  You're only passing in an `unsigned char` (which is converted to an `int`), so this character value is being interpreted as an address.  Using the wrong format specifier to `sprintf` invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

It looks like you were attempting to append to `output`.  The way to do that would be to only include the `%02x` format specifier, then on each loop iteration increment the pointer value `output` by 2 so that the next write happens in the correct place:

```
for (int n=0; n<64; n++, output+=2) {
   sprintf(output, "%02x", myData[n]);
}
```

Comment: Indeed, that fixed the problem without the need of initializing the output variable. Thank you for your explanation, things are more clear now :)